# Omnisharp format a whole directory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I made some changes to my omnisharp config and want to reformat all of my source, but the only way I actually know of to invoke omnisharp formatting is the VSCode format on save option. How do I run the formatter recursively in a directory?

Comment: if I understand correctly you want to change formatting as soon as typing completed? the you can find a settings in formatting option "Format on Type" should be ticked

Comment: No I want to run a command to format an entire directory's worth of files.